# How can I use 400 fields in a MS-Access form?

Tags: ms-access, field, max

I understand the maximum number of fields in a MS-Access form is 255. Is there any way to get around this limitation?

I am working with a mental health survey form that has approximately 400 fields.

I would like to create 1 data entry form to allow the mental health interviewer to enter all the responses on the one form.

I plan to use tabs to facilitate moving through the data entry.

Comment: Maybe you can post a screenshot or further explain what you're trying to do? We might be able to suggest an alternative design that would give the effect of being able to have unlimited fields.

Comment: I think you should read this post and my answer on it: http://is.gd/xrp0

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of fields in an Access recordsource is 255, as is the case with any Jet SQL statement. The limitation on the number of controls on a form is 754 *over the life of the form* (i.e., deleting a control does not gain you an additional control).

The design is clearly not correct, but as is so often the case, we don't get to choose on these things!

In that case, the only solution I can think of is a main form that has one field, the PK, and then a bunch of subforms with subsets of fields, e.g., 100 each. This means you have to be very careful about making sure that your subform saves its edits in its OnExit event (otherwise you'll get write conflicts).

And, no, it's not a good design at all.

But it is, at least, a workaround if you're forced to have 400 fields because you have an outside datasource that you can't properly normalize.

Comment: When you say over the life for the form, do mean that if I create a form, add 250 fields to it... then management changes it's mind and I need to redo the form completely deleting and replacing all 250 fields (and repeat this a few couple times) that the form will remember all the previous fields and I'll have to start the form fresh?

Or is it since you open the form in the current session. I shutdown access and come back the next day and I should be fine?

Comment: Fields!=Controls. As I said, the number of fields in a form or report's recordsource is limited to 255. If you drop 500 controls on a form and then delete them, you'll only be able to add 254 controls. The only way to reset it is to completely recreate the form (most easily done with Application.SaveAsText/.LoadFromText).